# How to separate the two values? Twig return sql group concat

Tags: twig

i need a help for make the result.

my sql request :

```
$posts = $db->prepare('SELECT
    CM.idpost,
    CM.title,
    CM.slug,
    CM.content,
    CM.cover,
    CM.date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(PC.id SEPARATOR ";") AS list_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(PC.cat_name SEPARATOR ";") AS list_cat_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(PC.icon SEPARATOR ";") AS list_icon,
    GROUP_CONCAT(PC.bg SEPARATOR ";") AS list_bg,
    GROUP_CONCAT(PC.slug_cat SEPARATOR ";") AS list_slug_cat,
    U.iduser,
    U.username,
    U.avatar
    FROM cms_posts CM
    LEFT JOIN relation_posts RP ON RP.id_post = CM.idpost
    LEFT JOIN cms_postcategory PC ON PC.id = RP.id_category
    LEFT JOIN users U ON U.iduser = CM.author
    GROUP BY CM.idpost
    ORDER BY CM.date DESC LIMIT '.$paginationStart.','.$limit.'');
```

this is what my sql query for my table returns: **Marketing;Général** in Twig :

{{ post.list_cat_name }}

[Picture demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwmKF.jpg)

I need the result :

```
<a href="{{idcategory"> Marketing </a>
<a href="{{idcategory}}"> Général</a>
```

Thanks for help <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got a string like `Marketing;Général`.  You need to create 2 links using the text for each as the link text.

I assume you similarly need to split the list_id for your `idcategory` value.

So something like this:

```
{% set categoryNames = post.list_cat_name | split(';') %}
{% set categoryIds = post.list_id | split(';') %}

{% for category in categoryNames %}
    <a href="{{categoryIds[loop.index0]}}"> {{category}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

- https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable
- https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html

Comment: You are the best guy, thanks for help ! <3